# Boolean query does not return expected data in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following document in Elasticsearch as reported by Kibana:

```
{"deviceId":"C1976429369BFE063ED8B3409DB7C7E7D87196D9","appId":"DisneyDigitalBooks.PlanesAdventureAlbum","ostype":"iOS"}
```

Why the following query does not return success?

```
[root@myvm elasticsearch-1.0.0]# curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/unique_app_install/_search?pretty=1' -d '
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [ {
        "term" : {
          "deviceId" : "C1976429369BFE063ED8B3409DB7C7E7D87196D9"
        }
      }, {
        "term" : {
          "appId" : "DisneyDigitalBooks.PlanesAdventureAlbum"
        }
      }, {
        "term" : {
          "ostype" : "iOS"
        }
      } ]
    }
  }
}'
```

Here is the response from Elasticsearch:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

As a side question, is this the fastest way to query the data in my case?

Thx in advance.

UPDATE:
Could it be related to the fact that I used the following mapping for this index?

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/unique_app_install -d '{
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 5
    },
    "mappings" : {
        "sdk_sync" : {
            "properties" : {
                "deviceId" : { "type" : "string" , "index": "not_analyzed"},
                "appId" : { "type" : "string" , "index": "not_analyzed"},
                "ostype" : { "type" : "string" , "index": "not_analyzed"}
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Comment: Are you looking in the correct index?

Comment: Yes, unique_app_install is the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the type of your document was right while inserting: sdk_sync.

I have used your items and for me it works. Using the following curl request give the right response for me:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/unique_app_install/sdk_sync/1 -d '{
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 5
    },
    "mappings" : {
        "sdk_sync" : {
            "properties" : {
                "deviceId" : { "type" : "string" , "index": "not_analyzed"},
                "appId" : { "type" : "string" , "index": "not_analyzed"},
                "ostype" : { "type" : "string" , "index": "not_analyzed"}
            }
        }
    }
}'

curl -XPOST localhost:9200/unique_app_install/sdk_sync/1 -d '{
    "deviceId":"C1976429369BFE063ED8B3409DB7C7E7D87196D9",
    "appId":"DisneyDigitalBooks.PlanesAdventureAlbum",
    "ostype":"iOS"
}'

curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/unique_app_install/_search?pretty=1' -d '
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [ {
        "term" : {
          "deviceId" : "C1976429369BFE063ED8B3409DB7C7E7D87196D9"
        }
      }, {
        "term" : {
          "appId" : "DisneyDigitalBooks.PlanesAdventureAlbum"
        }
      }, {
        "term" : {
          "ostype" : "iOS"
        }
      } ]
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: Thx, I think you are right, i might have missed the correct type name, I'll recheck that and let you know.

Comment: Thx that was the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specify the field NOT to be analyzed, every fields are analyzed by default.

It means that deviceId "C1976429369BFE063ED8B3409DB7C7E7D87196D9" will be indexed as "c1976429369bfe063ed8b3409db7c7e7d87196d9" (**lower case**).

You have to use term query or term filter with string in **LOWER CASE**.

> That is the reason why you should specify {"index": "not_analyzed"}
>   for the mapping.